# Is the architecture/blueprint available for the open source FHIR implementation on Azure?

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I wish to know the underlying architecture of the open source FHIR implementation in Azure. (Azure API too would be ideal but if this is not possible then that is fine)

Is there an image anywhere detailing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what exactly you are looking for. I have added a diagram of the layers in the architecture. All the code is available at https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server.

If your question is around how data are persisted and search parameter extraction, please see https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/Search.md

Hope this helps.

[image: Azure FHIR Server Architecture]

Comment: Apologies for being unclear!
Thank you for this, it is very usefull!

I dont suppose there is also one illustrating how all the azure components work together for the Open Source service ?

Comment: Again, it is not completely clear what you are asking. The components are layers in the architecture and plays various roles depending on the nature of the API calls. Are you looking for a call tree or something like that? If that is what you need, just run it in the debugger and try adding breakpoints in various places you are interested in.